# Redhat BRMS & Azure AD Integration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, drools, redhat-brms

Have anyone tried or know how to integrate BRMS (business central) with azure AD for authentication? currently, we use LDAP.

Comment: Have you look this MS document ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/administration/authenticating-users-with-azure-active-directory?tabs=singletenant%2Cadmintool

Comment: Hello @kyle, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) is a cloud service that provides identity and access capabilities for applications. The applications can be cloud-based, like on Microsoft Azure and Microsoft 365, and installed on-premises, like Business Central.

There are few prerequisites you need to address before integration of Azure AD auth with business central would suggest you to please refer this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/administration/authenticating-users-with-azure-active-directory?tabs=singletenant%2Cadmintool) for how to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating Red Hat Business Rules Management System (BRMS) with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) for authentication can provide centralized user management and Single Sign-On (SSO) capabilities.

Here's a high-level overview of the steps to integrate Red Hat BRMS with

- Set up an Azure AD tenant.
- Register your Red Hat BRMS application in Azure AD as a non-gallery application.
- Note down the Application (client) ID and Directory (tenant) ID from the Azure AD application registration. In Red Hat BRMS application, configure it to use Azure AD for authentication.
- This typically involves configuring the application's authentication settings to point to Azure AD endpoints for authentication and authorization.
- You may need to specify the Azure AD Directory (tenant) ID, Application (client) ID, and other relevant settings.

Test the integration between Red Hat BRMS and Azure AD by attempting to log in to the BRMS application using Azure AD credentials.
Verify that users can authenticate successfully and access the BRMS application with their Azure AD accounts.

Consider implementing role-based access control (RBAC) in your BRMS application based on Azure AD group membership or other attributes.
Ensure that appropriate access controls and permissions are configured in both Azure AD and Red Hat BRMS to enforce security policies and protect sensitive data.

By following these steps, you can integrate Red Hat BRMS with Azure AD for authentication, providing a seamless and secure login experience for users while leveraging Azure AD's centralized user management capabilities.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy - please read this carefully and consider if you should delete some or all of your answers